# How can I INSERT multiple rows by adding same value to ID's from other table thus creating new pairs?

Tags: sql, mariadb, magento2

I have 3 tables:

1. product
2. brand
3. brand_product

I want to INSERT pair of brand_id(which is say 35) and product_id in brand_product for all products that are LIKE '%chosen brand%'.

So far I got this, but it won't work:

```
INSERT INTO brand_product(brand_id, product_id)
VALUES ('426', (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku LIKE '%NIKE%'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select` if you want to insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO brand_product(brand_id, product_id)
    SELECT 426, entity_id
    FROM catalog_product_entity
    WHERE sku LIKE '%NIKE%';
```

Comment: Ah I understand it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query.

```
Insert into brand_product(brand_id, product_id)
VALUES ( select 426,entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku LIKE '%NIKE% ) ;
```

Comment: Is that correct syntax??  (Note that Gordon left out the `VALUES` and the parens.)

Comment: Yes it is we need to add values and  parentheses also.